# Is there a way to have Microsoft Exchange server override the from field in outgoing mail?

Tags: email, exchange, smtp

I need to know if it's possible on an exchange server to filter outgoing mail and override the from address in certain cases.

We have to set up many Exchange users who will only be able to access exchange through the outlook web access. All their outgoing e-mails when received from recipients outside our company should appear to be sent from a single generic address and not from the users' addresses.

Anyone knows whether this is possible or not?

Comment: Which version of Exchange?

Comment: Ideally it would be something working from exchange 2007 onwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your request, you can use Exchange Address Rewriting to accomplish this.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996806

(there are other links out there for Exchange 2007)

Outbound SMTP mail to other domains would be rewritten (so joe@domain.com could become support@domain.com), but internal would not.

Comment: thank you! this looks exactly like what I was looking for, I'll have a look